# DLL zOS dynamic

Tags: dynamic, dll, cobol, zos

I'm compiling a COBOL program as a DLL in zOS using the compiler options
PGMN(LM),DLL,EXPORTALL
When I do this, it also forces the compile to be NODYNAM.  In this context, is there some other parm I can use to force the CALLS to to other subprograms from this to be dynamic (i.e. resolved at run time).
I know I can use the CALL variable-name approach to accomplish this, but I can't do this with system routines like DSNELI, the DB2 call interface.

Does the IMPORT option have something to do with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All DLL's must be complied with NODYNAM. This cannot be avoided. As you pointed out using NODYNAM does
not preclude dynamic program calls using the `CALL var-name` approach. As long as you are using dynamic calls
to locally developed routines you will maintain all of the advantages of not having static linked modules in
your programs.

Be less concerned about static linked system modules such as `CALL 'DSNELI'`. These are
stub programs that will dynamically load the appropriate language interface module at 
run time. See [Universal Language Interface](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z_universallanguageinterface.htm).

Comment: Yes, using DSNULI instead of DSNELI resulted in the right DB2 call attach facility being pulled in at runtime.  According to that page there is a performance overhead but hopefully it will be a onetime thing at the very first SQL statement.

Comment: @ChuckLeviton I believe the biggest overhead hit will be on the first call, as it is with any other dynamically resolved reference. After that the overhead should be negligible.

Comment: Does this also apply when CALLing CBL2DLI?

Comment: @Frank I am no expert on IMS, but I would expect that CBL2DLI is similar to DSNxLI modules in that they are stubs. When initially called they are resolved to the approprate module at run time. Most of the overhead occurs on the first call. After that there should be little difference between "static" and "dynamic" calls with respect to performance.

Comment: Interesting!.. It's very similar behavior when compiling with Microfocus VS COBOL Workbench for Unix, a product which I co-labeled and managed for AT&T-IS back in the mid 80's.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want the calls to those system routines to be static.  The routines tend to be stubs that locate the "real" routine at runtime.

Comment: DLLs are new to us.  In our shop all our batch programs are compiled with DYNAM. This means that system routine calls are also resolved at runtime which has some positive implications for us that we'd like to continue to leverage on when we use DLLs.

Comment: And those system routine calls will continue to be resolved at runtime, as I said.

Comment: The DLL handler has to be static. But it will act like DYNAM as it loads the DLL modules.